# how to get all building names within a range from a given gps coordinates in postGIS?

Tags: postgresql, range, coordinates, distance, postgis

im making a panorama viewer, connected to a postgres db, I need to download building names, street names, interest points within a given range. 
I really appreciate if you could shed some light on this matter.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

As you did not give us some table specifications, an artificial example will have to do.

```
WITH yourpoint AS (
    SELECT
        st_transform(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(yourlon, yourlat), 4326), yourgeomsrid) AS point
)
SELECT 
    building.name
FROM 
    building, yourpoint
WHERE
    ST_Dwithin(building.the_geom, yourpoint.point, 400)
```

Now, let's have a look at the interesting parts. At first we need a geometry to accomodate your given point in the correct coordinate system. I created a substatement (CTE) that generates such a point. Maybe the point is within your database, though.

Important: For calculating distances, the point you specify and the geometries have to be in the same coordinate system. Thus, I encapsulated the `st_makepoint` with `st_setsrid`, which adds coordinate system information to the point. GPS usually is in WGS84 which has SRID 4326. Now, we have to transform that point to the coordinate system of your point data - the SRID therefore you have to know.

All the magic for finding the buildings close by happens in the `WHERE` clause. `ST_Dwithin` looks up all geometries that have a distance of less than 400 (measured in the unit of your coordinate system) to each other.

See [the postgis manual](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_DWithin.html) for details.

---

### EDIT

If your coordinates are in WGS84, you should use the geography datatype:

```
WITH yourpoint AS (
    SELECT
        geography(st_setsrid(st_makepoint(yourlon, yourlat), 4326)) AS point
)
SELECT 
    building.name
FROM 
    building, yourpoint
WHERE
    ST_Dwithin(Geography(building.the_geom), yourpoint.point, 400)
```

Comment: thanks thilo, so at least when I run this SQL code, dont get any error, but it seems i'm not getting how srid and other conversions are working here...cause i get 0 row in return. How would I know what srid i should put for "yourgeomsrid"? and also about the 400, again how would i figure out the units? thanks so much for your patience answering a noob :)

Comment: Well, what SRID have your geometries in the database? `SELECT st_srid(the_geom) FROM building` should tell you. The unit of the distances depends on the coordinate system in use.

Comment: Ok - then your geometries are also in WGS84. Ah, that rises another question: What PostGIS version are you using? If >= 1.5 what datatype are your geometries? `GEOMETRY` or `GEOGRAPHY`?

Comment: the postgis version is 2.0.1, geom

Comment: In this case I would suggest you to use the `Geography` type for your geometries. See http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/geography.html. I will edit my answer to do this conversion on the fly; however, altering the data model might be a good idea.

Comment: One more remark: If you need great performance it might be a good idea to switch to a cartesian coordinate system - see the article I linked to for further information.

Comment: thilo, thanks, but this is what i get "ERROR:  Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type" however my long and lat are like 28,40

Comment: Obviously not all of them - which one is faulty you have to find out.

Comment: Thilo are you interested to participate in this project? I'm running short on time and technicalities in this area are slowing me down. please let me know, you can contact me on kourosh06@gmail.com thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20509/discussion-between-kourosh-and-thilo)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
select * FROM 
    LayerName
WHERE
    ST_Dwithin(LayerName.the_geom, 
    GeomFromText('POINT(x,y)',-1)
    , radius)
```

layerName is your layer,
x,y from GPS,
-1 is your srid,
radius is radius of your buffer(double)

Comment: hi navid, i'm working on this project and very new to postGIS, and due to time limits, I would like to ask you if you wish to participate for the postgres and postgis part of this project. thank you.

Comment: I have no problem and you can have contact with navid.benami@gmail

Comment: i got delivery failed message, is this email add correct? thanks

Comment: :D no :|:D navid.behnami@gmail.com